# Is it OK to have 10 rotating banners from Hostgator in the same banner slot?

Tags: advertising, hostgator

I have 728x90 position on my blog and I have a php script that randomly choose number from 0 - 9 and display a random banner from Hostgator affiliate banners.

Should I stick with one or is the rotating thing actually better and can bring more attention from the visitors as only one or two rotating banners in the banner slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't it be? People usually eliminate ads from the mental map of your site - and by that logic having the same banner would be more harmful in the long (LONG) term.

Now, by rotating, do you mean literally it scrolls through during the same pageload, or each pageload it will load a different image? Having a scrolling banner, depending on the size, placement, your site design, if the image clashes with the design, etc. etc. After that, it's all aesthetics and falls into the Graphic Design category.

Comment: By rotating I mean aggragation 1:10 on the same banner position. Different banner for each page load.

Comment: Then you should be fine; plenty of large websites use that method to maximize the advertising - Facebook, Google AdSense, etc.